# Why is the default constructor getting called twice when I included a "parameter"?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor, default-constructor

I'm a bit confused. When I added an argument for the default constructor `baseClass` (JACOB), my program outputs that there were two objects that were added: JACOB and ANONYMOUS.

If I omitted "JACOB", I would get only "ANONYMOUS" which is to be expected. My question is, why is it that when I pass "JACOB", I still get the "ANONYMOUS" object in my program?

(main.cpp)

```
//*************************************************************************
#include <iostream>     //inclusion of support for doing input & output
#include <string>       //inclusion of support of the string class
#include <vector>       //inclusion of support of the vector class
#include <fstream>       //inclusion of support of file I/O
using namespace std;    //declare access to standard stuff like cin, cout


#include "baseClass.h" 
#include "childClassA.h" 
#include "childClassB.h" 



void test()
{     

    //*************************************************************************
    //Observe the implicit calls to constructors of the base and the child classes
    //*************************************************************************
      baseClass jacob("JACOB"); // <-- Question about this one

}   

int  main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

baseClass.cpp

```
//*************************************************************************
//  Base class implementation
//*************************************************************************
#include "baseClass.h"

int baseClass::count = 0;

baseClass::baseClass(string name)
{
      baseName = name;
      ++count;
      cout  << endl
                  << baseName
                  << ", a new baseClass object is CONSTRUCTED."
                  << endl << "Now "
                  << count << " baseClass objects in total."
                  << endl << endl;
}

baseClass::~baseClass()
{
      --count;
      cout  << endl
                  << baseName
                  << ", a baseClass object is DESTRUCTED."
                  << endl << "Now "
                  << count << " baseClass class objects in total."
                  << endl << endl;

}

void baseClass::output()
{
      cout << endl << "Hello! I am " << baseName << ", a baseClass object " << endl;
}
```

baseClass.h

```
//*************************************************************************
//  Base class declaration
//*************************************************************************
#ifndef BASE_CLASS_H

#define BASE_CLASS_H

using namespace std;
#include <string>       //inclusion of support of the string class
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class baseClass
{     public:
            baseClass(string name = "ANONYMOUS");

            virtual ~baseClass();   //What is the effect of virtual??
            //~baseClass();               //What happens if no virtual??

            virtual void output();  //What is the effect of virtual??
            //void output();        //What happens if no virtual??

            static int count;

      private:
            string baseName;
};

#endif // Matching the starting #ifndef BASE_CLASS_H
```

Output:

```
JACOB, a new baseClass object is CONSTRUCTED.
Now 1 baseClass objects in total.


ANONYMOUS, a new baseClass object is CONSTRUCTED.
Now 2 baseClass objects in total.
```

Comment: Can you please edit this question to remove the code that _isn't_ necessary for exhibiting the issue you're asking about? Right now this example is neither minimal (surely almost all of `test` is irrelevant if the first line alone is what you have questions about) nor reproducible (we don't have definitions for `childClassA` or `childClassB`.) It'd be easier to tell what's going on with the code if there isn't a bunch of irrelevant and incomplete code cluttering the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and removed the irrelevant portions out of my code. Please let me know if I should add/remove anything further :)

Comment: Can you add how the child class looks like and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The output of your current edited version gives "JACOB" as its output and no "ANONYMOUS" .

Comment: I copied your code into https://godbolt.org/z/chjMvh9vY and I don't see ANONYMOUS in the output. Are you sure you're still seeing this problem? And why doesn't your sample output include any DESTRUCTED messages?

Comment: Have you checked that this version of the code still reproduces your issue? When I compile and run this code, I get what I would consider to be the expected output. The construction and destruction of a single `baseClass`, name of `JACOB`, is logged. This suggests that the issue was actually somewhere in the code you ended up deleting. Perhaps one of your `childClassX` constructors calls the default `baseClass` constructor?

Comment: I just checked my code and you're right. When I got rid of everything else, it appears that only ```JACOB``` is logged. I think the problem persists with the child classes. I'm using C++98 and Visual Studio, but I don't think those are the sources of the problems. I included a Google Drive link with all of the files, hopefully that might clear things up a bit. 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YMDeZJRJrXCTHZV2HVVIKli0ab9o5tuO?usp=sharing

Comment: (I made the project on Visual Studio and placed everything on that Google Drive link. If including only the .h/.cpp files would make things easier, please let me know)

Comment: Ideally you would figure out the code that's necessary to exhibit the issue yourself and edit it so that the question itself includes that code, instead of an offsite link. However it is indeed the case that both `childClassA` and `childClassB` are calling the default `baseClass` constructor. Take a look at your textbook or other reference material where it describes how derived classes invoke base class constructors to see why this is happening.

Comment: Ah! Got it! Thank you very much for that clarification! 
Also, I understand, I'll make sure that I remove the other code that isn't needed beforehand so it's a bit easier to read. Thank you again for your explanation!

Comment: A link to an example on https://godbolt.org or similar online compiler is a good way to demonstrate your problem (but you must still include the code in the question itself) and also allows potential answerers to more easily make and test changes to the code.